# Node.js - Memory leak when static file connection is dropped (Static files)

Tags: node.js, file, memory, static, express

I am getting a memory leak when I prevent a file from loading fully loading. E.g.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/js/lib.js"></script>`

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. 
Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at Socket.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at Socket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:663:33)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.once (events.js:179:8)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:26)
```

And when I remove this line I stop getting memory leaks:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')));
```

How can I try to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using nginx to serve static files! Might just be a temporary solution, but it works.